# Pass argument when initializing ThreadLocal variable

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

In my Java application I want to have a pool of threads (I use ExecutorService for this) that connect to a memcached server to issue some requests. I would like that each Thread has its own connection that is opened once and should be kept during the whole running time. I was planning to use the following code that I found in another question:

**Executor Service**

```
ExecutorService threadPool = 
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5, Executors.defaultThreadFactory());
```

**Runnables executed by the Threads in the pool**

```
public class SocketTask implements Runnable {
private String workDetails;
private static final ThreadLocal<Socket> threadLocal = 
       new ThreadLocal<Socket>(){
    @Override
    protected Socket initialValue(){
        return new Socket();
    }           
};

public SocketTask(String details){              
    this.workDetails = details;
}

public void run(){      
    Socket s = getSocket(); //gets from threadlocal
    //send data on socket based on workDetails, etc.
}

public static Socket getSocket(){
    return threadLocal.get();
}
```

}

My question is, when I initialize the socket how can I do it so I am able to pass an argument (say a String with the IP of the memcached server) to the new Socket() call?

Answer (score 1):

Example with a factory instead of static fields.

Factory creation:

```
final SocketTaskFactory socketTaskFactory = new SocketTaskFactory("...", 12345);
```

Factory use (instead of now "new SocketTask(...)"):

```
Runnable socketTask = socketTaskFactory.createSocketTask("the work details");
```

Factory code, including the socket task as an inner class:

```
package threadlocal;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketTaskFactory
{
    final String host;
    final int port;

    public SocketTaskFactory(String host, int port)
    {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public Runnable createSocketTask(String workDetails)
    {
        return new SocketTask(workDetails);
    }

    final ThreadLocal<Socket> socketForThread = new ThreadLocal<Socket>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Socket initialValue()
        {
            try
            {
                return new Socket(host, port);
            }
            catch(IOException exception)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(exception);
            }
        }
    };

    private class SocketTask implements Runnable
    {
        private final String workDetails;

        public SocketTask(String workDetails)
        {
            this.workDetails = workDetails;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Socket socket = socketForThread.get();

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the ThreadLocal should be inside the class SocketTask no?

Comment: Then each SocketTask instance would have its own instance of ThreadLocal, which is exactly what doesn't work. Otherwise, you wouldn't have had the problem, and asked the question, in the first place.

Comment: The factory is just a way to make the thing not a static field. There is still just one per factory, one for many instances. But it is way more flexible than using a static field, which is usually a bad idea because it often requires changing that and make it not static at some point in the near future.

Comment: The ThreadLocal is a singleton relative to all socket tests created by one instance of the factory, so they all share the same sockets, one per thread. Otherwise there would be one socket per thread and per socket task, each would have one socket for each thread it has ever run in.

Comment: what i want to achieve is having one socket per thread in the pool. Not one per every SocketTask. So as the pool has a fixed size (say 5 threads) I will onlöy have 5 open sockets

Comment: That is exactly the reason that you want exactly one instance of ThreadLocal. Because there will be one Socket per ThreadLocal and per thread that ever uses a ThreadLocal instance.

Comment: With exactly one ThreadLocal instance, every thread will use the same instance every time, and therefore always get the same Socket.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my answer. No it didn't. Actually I gave the whole thing a second thought and I didn't need ThreadLocals or ExecutorService in the first place. I just wrote a Runnable class where I store the connection as a class argument and it is opened during the initialization of the thread. In my opinion, this design is cleaner and you can easily see what is going on.

Comment: Completely changing a question is considered poor style. Some or most answers will have nothing to do with the question anymore. This is confusing for everybody. Please create a new question when you find out that the question itself was flawed, and comment on the original question.

Comment: And yes, things are indeed much simpler when you don't need thread local data.

Comment: Wait... you didn't change the question, did you? The layout seemed to look different at first glance :)

Comment: I will change it you are right. It was the 1st time I posted so sorry about that.

Comment: No, please don't change the question :) The question isn't wrong just because you don't need thread locals for what you're doing outside of stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

The `java.net.Socket` class can be initialized with overloaded constructors. The one that matches your requirement closer is probably the following:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("yourHost", yourPort);
```

**Also...**

- You can use `static` fields to define host and port, and reference them within `initialValue` simply with the field's name

as `SocketTask.this.[theFieldNames]`

See [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html).

Comment: The thing is that "yourHost" will ve stored in a variable (maybe an attribute of the class SocketTask) , how do you do it so it is visible inside the intialValue() method?

Comment: @Moises more edits. Got confused myself. Should be clearer now.

Comment: Instance fields do not need to be final. Only stack-local fields need to be final in order to be accessible from a Clojure, until Java 8, where it suffices when they are effectively final.

Comment: @yeoman you're right. Don't know why I'm getting so confused over this. Fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create the ThreadLocal just as `ThreadLocal<Socket> soc = new ThreadLocal<>();` and once you need it check `if (soc.get() == null) {soc.set(...);}` with any constructor/arguments you desire perhaps.